# How do I assess whether my ASP.NET web application is easy to break into?

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, iis, web-applications

I have to develop an ASP.NET web application and publish it in Windows Azure so that it runs there under IIS7. I don't have any serious experience developing such applications. I constantly hear that "site X was broken into because it was doing Y in a very stupid way". I'm kind of paranoid that I might also be doing Y (and also Z) in a very stupid way and have my application hacked in no time.

Is there a good guideline of making well protected ASP.NET web sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) site and set of guidelines. They are rather extensive.

They have [several tools](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Project) that will detect some types of vulnerabilites.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start from the recommended Microsoft [Asp.net security practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650037.aspx) and browse the various subsections from here. I think it's Asp.net 2.0 related but most of the guidelines still apply (what version will you be working on?).

**EDIT**: here's the [latest version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91f66yxt.aspx) for .net 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [OWASP Top 10 for .NET Developers](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html) series. This will give you a step-by-step guide on how to protect against specific vulnerabilities for apps using the ASP.NET framework.